# How do I remove an item from an array that consists of functions within a class?

Tags: arrays, swift, error-handling, uibezierpath, swift-playground

When I try to remove an item from the following array:

```
var actualFormNamesFromFormClass = [Forms.iPhoneForm, Forms.AppleForm, Forms.swiftBirdForm, Forms.watchForm, Forms.macForm]
```

Using the following code:

```
actualFormNamesFromFormClass.remove(at: i)
```

I get the error "Expression resolves to an unused function". My array actualFormNamesFromFormClass consists of functions that construct an array of type [UIBezierPath]. I want to remove an item from the array at index i, but I get that error. The Forms is a class and after the dot is the function in that class.

Comment: The compiler really shouldn't error on that; I filed a bug here: https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-7297

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always add `_ =` to the start:

```
_ = actualFormNamesFromFormClass.remove(at: i)
```

since `_` means "I don't need this".